# jquery tabs and client side validation gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, validation

I have a tabbed panel created using the jquery ui tabs and where each tab is loaded with ajax. On each of these tabs i have a number of nested forms.  I'm using formtastic to create the form, and semantic_form_for to created the nested forms.

I have the client_side validation gem installed and working on my 'normal' forms.  On the forms within the tabbed panels, it does nothing.  I'm guessing that this might be because when the tab content is loaded with ajax the client_side_validation functions need to be bound to the inputs.  Anyone have any experience of this? Even suggestions about where to begin debugging the problem would be much appreciated ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I instinctively didn't like the idea of reloading the js files as suggested in the first answer, though the answer was helpful in pointing me in the right direction. Sure enough, a little way further along, the reimported files started to cause problems of their own so I did a bit more digging. To set up the tabs, I'm now using js like this:

```
    contacttabs.tabs({
            load: function(event, ui){
                   $('a.load_to_enquiries_tab').live("click", function() {
                        $('#enquiries').load(this.href, function() {
                              set_styles();
                              $(function() {
                                    $('form[data-validate]').validate();
                              })
                              return false;
                        });
                        return false;
                  });
});
```

The key lines are the ones in the callback which call validate() on the forms in the tab.  This is a method in the client_side_validation validations.js file which binds the client side validation goodness to the form. This works for me now - hopefully it will help someone else too.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to the tab that has the validation problems

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "rails.validations" %>  
<%= form_for @yourform, :validate => true do |f|%>
#Your code here
<% end %>
```

**Edit:**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.6.2.min' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery_ujs', 'application' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "rails.validations" %>  
<%= form_for @company, :validate => true do |f|%>
  <div class="field">
    <b>Company Name:<b><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :address %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :telephone %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :telephone %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: i understand why you are asking - but actually the tab is pretty complex, and I don't want to put people off answering by pasting a lot of code for them to read.  I'm rather hoping someone will just 'know' the answer

Comment: I'll edit my post with my working validations tab then, all I can do!

Comment: thanks ahmet - i've also stuck some of the code in a pastie ..

http://pastie.org/2542385

Comment: ah - looks like i get a more interesting bunch of errors with the jquery include tag added - which makes sense.  Thanks for your help +1 for that.  I'd love it if someone could provide an answer that didn't involve reloading jquery though!

Comment: Same for some reason I always need to re-add the JQuery include tags even though there in my view/layouts